# Trying to fit the Gaussian function to data

Tags: python, scipy, gaussian

I'm trying to fit some data that is approximately Gaussian to the function in python using the curve_fit method. For the initial guesses for the parameters I've calculated the mean and standard deviation of the data. However, I'm getting a really bad fit and I'm not sure why. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np
import math

def func(x, mu, sig):
    return (1./(sig*math.sqrt(2*math.pi)))*np.exp(-np.power(x-mu,2.)/(2*np.power(sig, 2.)));

xdata = np.linspace(4, 14, 21)
ydata = np.array([0.2,0.8,1.8,1.9,5.9,7,11,12.6,14,13.3,11.8,9.3,5.2,3.1,1.5,0.7,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.1])
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata,[4.8,5.1])
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
```

The fitted model (in red) looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM4mi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a nonsense answer is because you're trying to fit the Gaussian function of a normalised curve. See the difference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function).

Instead, if you use the generalised form with 3 parameters, you get a much better fit.

```
def generalised_gaussian(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.exp(-np.power((x-b)/(2*c**2), 2))

xdata = np.linspace(4, 14, 21)
ydata = np.array([0.2,0.8,1.8,1.9,5.9,7,11,12.6,14,13.3,11.8,9.3,5.2,3.1,1.5,0.7,0.4,0.1,0.3,0.1,0.1])
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'b-', label='data')

popt, pcov = curve_fit(generalised_gaussian, xdata, ydata)
plt.plot(xdata, generalised_gaussian(xdata, *popt), 'r-', label='fit')
```

[image: Fit]